# What does it mean to define a type with no constructors in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, abstract-data-type

I saw [this OCaml code in the Coq codebase](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/api/coq/Genarg/ArgT/index.html#type-tag):

```
type ('a, 'b, 'c) tag
```

which seems we create the type `tag` that takes three type arguments `'a, 'b, 'c` but has no constructors…? So how do we even construct values for this type?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is in reference to a specification in an interface, this simply means that constructors are not exposed as part of the interface.

However, this does not mean there is no way to obtain a value of this type. In this case, it appears the primary (possibly only; I am unfamiliar with Coq's API) way to obtain a value of this type would be to use [`get_arg_tag`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/api/coq/Genarg/index.html#val-get_arg_tag) from the containing module.

Comment: how do I find the valid values of tag?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @CharlieParker it’s an *abstract type*: you know it exists but you don’t know anything about its implementation (constructors and shape). So you are not able to construct a value directly, *nor even* to pattern-match on a value of that type. You can only create and consume values of that type through library-provided functions. There is a variation of this, in which you expose the constructors of a type, so you can pattern-match, while still forbidding direct creation. See [the `private` keyword](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/privatetypes.html).